# How to combine the last two objects into single object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of multiple objects and the last two objects contains data for the same column in a table. Is it possible to to return the last two objects from this array into one object so that when I loop this array I see the data for the last two objects in the same column?

```
{
  row: [
    {
      name: 'CHK_OUT_TYPE',
      value: ''
    },
    ...
    {
      name: 'PRI_PHN_AREA_CD',
      value: '954'
    },
    {
      name: 'PRI_PHN_NR',
      value: '3333333'
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<tbody>
          {row.map(data => (
              return <td>{data.value}</td>
            ))}
          </tbody>
```

### **Expected output:**

```
  | 954 3333333
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: just updated my post with the expected output. For examle, the values for the last two objects should display in the same column rather then having their own columns

Comment: Still unclear. Please explain in detail and show the **rendered** HTML result you're expecting.

Comment: `return <td>{data.value}</td>` is not valid Javascript syntax. If you are using JSX, tag your question accordingly!

Comment: You can't use `map()` for this. It processes one element at a time, and returns a new array with the same number of elements as the input.

Comment: How do you want to combine the `name` properties of the two elements?

Comment: Also `<tbody>` cannot have `td` children; only `tr` allowed there.

Comment: the whole point of having structured objects is to keep things orderly. Maybe consider creating another row of your data that has the values you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

```js
const row = [
  {
    name: 'CHK_OUT_TYPE',
    value: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'PRI_PHN_AREA_CD',
    value: '954'
  },
  {
    name: 'PRI_PHN_NR',
    value: '3333333'
  }
];

const merge_two_items = (a, b) => ({
  name: a.name + ' + ' + b.name,
  value: a.value + ' ' + b.value
});

const merge_two_items_r = (b, a) => merge_two_items(a, b);

const merge_last_two_1 = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, item, index) =>
      index === arr.length - 1 ?
        acc :
        [
          ...acc,
          index === arr.length - 2 ?
            merge_two_items(item, arr[index + 1]) :
            item
        ],
    []
  );

const merge_last_two_2 = (arr) => {
  let copy = [...arr];
  
  copy.push(merge_two_items_r(copy.pop(), copy.pop()));
  
  return copy;
};

console.log(merge_last_two_1(row));
console.log(merge_last_two_2(row));
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is ALWAYS going to be the last two values then you can simply get access to the last element of the array using `row[row.length-1].value` this should return the last element, `row[row.length-2].value` should return the 2nd to the last element